# Ruby and mongo_mapper error

Tags: ruby, mongomapper

I have a problem running any Ruby application with mongo_mapper.

`include MongoMapper::Document` in my simple class rises an error: `...2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.14.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/active_model.rb:9:in <module:ActiveModel>': uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml (NameError)`

I have gems for ActiveModel::Serializers and ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain but using the bundler to run the application solves the problem.